# Functional integration (simplest trivial case, and simplest non--trivial case)

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration, the functional integral is defined as

$$
\int G[f][Df]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dots\int_{-\infty}^\infty G[f] \prod df(x)
 $$

I am trying to understand this better using examples. Can anyone give a simple trivial functional integral (and integrate it), then a very simple but non-trivial example (and also integrate it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the fact that if $n\in\Bbb N$ and $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is symmetric with only positive eigenvalues, $$\int_{\Bbb R^n}\exp\left(-\frac12 x^TAx+J^Tx\right)d^nx=\sqrt{\det(2\pi A^{-1})}\exp\left(\frac12 J^TA^{-1}J\right).$$We get a functional integral with an $n\to\infty$ limit that makes the vectors $J,\,x$ to functions, and the matrix $A$ a linear operator on functions, hereafter $\widehat{A}$. Since dot products such as $J^Tx=\sum_i J_ix_i$ becomes integrals when we do this, the end result is $$\int\exp\left(\int \left(-\frac12\varphi\widehat{A}\varphi+J\varphi\right)dx\right)\mathcal{D}\varphi=\exp\left(\frac12\int J\widehat{A}^{-1}Jdx\right).$$Note that the function analogous to our previous $x$ is now labelled $\varphi$, and it is a function of our new dummy variable, which is also called $x$. (Sorry if it's confusing, but I'm trying to stick to the most popular notation for each equation.) The functional integral operator $\int\mathcal{D}\varphi$ is over a space of functions, and has been defined to absorb such overall numerical factors as to obviate the determinant-dependent surd from the previous result. Note also that $D:=\widehat{A}^{-1}$ is an inverse of $\widehat{A}$ in the sense $\widehat{A}D(x-y)=\delta(x-y)$, where the argument of the Dirac delta is over the same space as $x$ is the functional derivative.

So, that's [every physicist's favourite functional integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Integrals_with_differential_operators_in_the_argument); to them, $D$ is a *Green's function* or a *propagator*. Physics is one of the best places to encounter contenders for "simple non-trivial cases" you can evaluate. The example above can be used to build solutions to harder problems, using perturbative methods; see Sec. 1.1.4 and 7.5 [here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnChalker/theory/lecture-notes.pdf). Sec. 1.2.2 (ibid.) proves that in non-relativistic quantum mechanics $$\int\exp\left(\frac{\text{i}}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\left(\frac12 m\dot{x}^2-V\left(x\left(t\right)\right)\right)\right)\mathcal{D}x(t)=\left\langle x_i\left|\exp\left(\frac{-\text{i}\hat{H}t}{\hbar}\right)\right|x_f\right\rangle,$$where this time the dummy-variable function is named $x$ and depends on $t$. Here the initial state is at $x=x_i,\,t=t_i$, and the final state is at $x=x_f,\,t=t_f$.